# Are wall anchors necessary for hanging a small speaker?

Tags: hanging, drywall-anchor

I'd like two hang a pair of speakers on my wall.  They are 6.8lb each.  It is designed to hang on two screw heads spaced 1.5in apart. (*Photo below*)

I'm looking for recommendations on hanging.

1. I have a bunch of 3M command strips.  (Just the strips).  I'm not sure if there's a plate or something I can get for it that would work with the speaker.  This would be ideal as I don't have to put holes in my wall
2. Can I just put two (drywall) screws directly in the drywall for each?  They would not align to a stud.
3. Otherwise, do I need to use a drywall anchor of some sort?  I'm not sure about using two right next to each other.  One is probably enough to hold the weight, but then the speaker wouldn't be straight.

[image]

Comment: Drywall screws are not used for attaching stuff to drywall. They're for attaching drywall to the studs.

Comment: you could hang them the same as a picture ... use one screw ... attach a hanging wire to back of speakers ... or file a notch in the bottom of the speaker bracket

Comment: I understand, I just happen to have a box of drywall screws on hand.  True, I could use a wire

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @user263983. Use plastic drywall anchors that go with the size of flathead screw that fits properly into receivers on the backs of the speakers. The heads of the screws must be small enough to fit inside the bottoms of the slots and large enough to be retained in the smaller tops of the slots.

Drill square to the wall so the screws are perpendicular to the wall. Drive the screws in so that the bracket just barely slip fits between the underside of the screw head and the plastic anchor or the wall.

If you don't have a drill or don't want to drill, there are anchors with a sharp end that you force into the drywall and then twist with a screwdriver to pull into the wall. Get the right size, and use two for each speaker. [Self drilling drywall anchors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FCZ8I3I)

Comment: OK, I have a drill, i just wanted to minimize damage to the wall

Answer (score -1):

You should have no trouble hanging those speakers with two drywall screws 1.5" apart. When screwing in the screws, angle the points  down slightly and torgue them slowly. Just make sure you're in solid drywall and not a seam.

Comment: I suspect you mean to angle the points downward, as the alternative don't make as much sense.

Comment: @fred_dot_u  Totally correct....

Comment: Easy anchors may be used.  Such weight drywall screw not enough.

Comment: @user263983  Tell that to the 9 lb mirror I hung 40 years ago.  :-)

Comment: I can only repeat the comment of @brhans, drywall screws is only for fasten drywall to studs.

Comment: DV???  What a joke!

Comment: Jack is probably right, but for heavy things with no inserts in drywall, rather than a screw I recommend sewing pins.  If you put them in 30 degrees downward and 2mm apart they leave little mark and carry a good load.

Comment: I would also note that I've helped out people who skipped inserts before and just ended up drilling and putting inserts in the holes left by screw tearout.

Comment: @KH  And sometimes you don't even have to drill, just shove in the insert.